# Sqoop export to RDBMS .lzo .gz files more than 64 MB loading duplicates

Tags: hadoop, export, gzip, sqoop, lzo

Using sqoop 1.3

Trying to export hdfs output to mysql table

Everything works as expected while loading an uncompressed file of size over 300MB

But while loading compressed files (.gz and .lzo) of sizes 75 MB or 79 MB, I see double the rows loaded into the table. This doesn't happen when the size of compressed file is 60MB or less (guessing something related to 64 MB , block size). Some operations I have done in the above context :

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 bhargavn bhargavn 354844413 Nov 16 02:27 large_file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhargavn bhargavn  15669507 Nov 21 03:41 small_file.lzo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bhargavn bhargavn  75173037 Nov 21 03:46 large_file.lzo

bash-3.2$ wc -l large_file
247060 large_file

bash-3.2$ sqoop export --connect 'jdbc:mysql://db.com/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round&    rewriteBatchedStatements=true' 
--table table_with_large_data 
--username sqoopuser 
--password sqoop 
--export-dir /user/bhargavn/workspace/data/sqoop-test/large_file.lzo 
--fields-terminated-by '\001' -m 1
[21/11/2012:05:52:28 PST] main      INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
[21/11/2012:05:57:03 PST] main      INFO com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase:     Transferred 143.3814 MB in 312.2832 seconds (470.1584 KB/sec)
[21/11/2012:05:57:03 PST] main      INFO com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase:     Exported 494120 records.

mysql> select count(1) from table_with_large_data;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|   494120 |
+----------+

mysql> truncate table_with_large_data;
bash-3.2$ sqoop export --connect 'jdbc:mysql://db.com/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=round&    rewriteBatchedStatements=true' 
--table table_with_large_data 
--uername sqoopuser 
--password sqoop 
--export-dir /user/bhargavn/workspace/data/sqoop-test/large_file
--fields-terminated-by '\001' 
-m 1
[21/11/2012:06:05:35 PST] main      INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:  map 0%     reduce 0%
[21/11/2012:06:08:06 PST] main      INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient:  map 100%     reduce 0%
[21/11/2012:06:08:06 PST] main      INFO com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase:     Transferred 338.4573 MB in 162.5891 seconds (2.0817 MB/sec)
[21/11/2012:06:08:06 PST] main      INFO com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.ExportJobBase:     Exported 247060 records.
mysql> select count(1) from table_with_large_data;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|   247060 |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you might hit a known bug[1] that Sqoop needs to fix on their side.

Would you mind signing to Sqoop user mailing list [2] and describing your issue there? I'm more than confident that Sqoop developers will jump in to troubleshoot this particular issue.

Jarcec

Links:

1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-721

2: http://sqoop.apache.org/mail-lists.html